# How to get stdout & stderr on subprocess.Popen when the subprocess crashes or timeouts

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I couldn't find the way to get the stdout and stderr from subprocess.Popen when the process crashes or reaches timeout. I've added try-exception clauses to catch those cases, but on the exception handler because the Popen function failed I don't have the stdout & stderr variables, and the exception object 'e' although having e.output & e.stderr they are None...
I tried also extract the stdout and stderr from the proc variable, but couldn't find the right way to do that, if possible.
See example code below.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_full, cwd=cwd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, env=env)
try:
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(timeout=TIMEOUT_SEC)
    return_code = proc.returncode
    stdout_str = stdout
    stderr_str = stderr
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    proc.kill()
    #kill_proc()  # I use this instead of the previous line because proc.kill() doesn't kill my process for some reason...
    stdout_str = e.output
    stderr_str = e.stderr
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    stdout = e.output
    stderr = e.stderr
except Exception as e:
    stdout = e.output
    stderr = e.stderr
```

BTW, this is my kill_proc() function (because proc.kill() doesn't really kill the process for me):

```
def kill_proc():
    process_name = "my_external_proccess.exe"            # process name
    for process in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
        try:
            if process.info['name'].lower() == process_name.lower():
                print(f"{process_name} is already running. Terminating it...")
                process.terminate()
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
```

Comment: You might want to prefer using [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Here is an approach that *might* work **if the executable being run by `subprocess.Popen` flushes its output as it proceeds**.

The idea is to run `subprocess.Popen` in a separate `multiprocessing.Process` instance and it is this instance that is being timed for completion. The process will be passed two queues, one for stdout and one for stderr, and for each output stream a thread will be started to read lines from the stream and put it into one of the queues. The main process will "timeout" the process by specifying a time value to `join()`. Whether the task has completed or not, any lines that have been put to the queues so far will be retrieved and displayed. If the process is still running, it will then be terminated. Note that in the demo "executable" I flush stdout after each print statement. Also note that the program terminates after the `TIMEOUT` value of 2 seconds (more or less) has passed.

```py
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from threading import Thread
from queue import Empty

def run_subprocess(stdout_queue, stderr_queue):
    def process_output(stream, queue):
        for line in iter(stream.readline, ''):
            queue.put(line)

    import subprocess
    import os

    cmd_full = f'test.py 100.0'
    cwd = '.' # Current directory
    env = os.environ

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_full, cwd=cwd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, env=env)
    t1 = Thread(target=process_output(proc.stdout, stdout_queue))
    t2 = Thread(target=process_output(proc.stderr, stderr_queue))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    proc.wait()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

def main():
    TIMEOUT_SEC = 2

    def print_queue(queue):
        try:
            while True:
                print(queue.get(block=False), end='')
        except Empty as e:
            pass

    stdout_queue = Queue()
    stderr_queue = Queue()
    p = Process(target=run_subprocess, args=(stdout_queue, stderr_queue))
    p.start()
    p.join(TIMEOUT_SEC)

    print('stdout:')
    print_queue(stdout_queue)

    print()
    print('stderr:')
    print_queue(stderr_queue)

    exit_code = p.exitcode
    if exit_code is None:
        p.terminate() # If not already finished
    print()
    print('Exit code =', exit_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import time

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        # No command line argument so create subprocess:
        main()
    else:
        # Invoked by subprocess.Popen call:
        sleep_time = float(sys.argv[1])
        print('starting', flush=True)
        print(f'Sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds ...', flush=True)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        print('ending', flush=True)
```

Prints:

```None
stdout:
starting
Sleeping for 100.0 seconds ...

stderr:

Exit code = None
```

Comment: Hi Booboo, Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but it doesn't really do the work: when it reaches the proc.communicate() is returns to the process and then it is again stuck there... You can see that if you change in your example the argument from 3.0 sec to 300.0 for example. You will see that the timeout will stop the process after the right amount of time, but then it returns to the process and keeps waiting for the entire 300 sec, which beats the whole idea of stopping that process in the middle...
BTW, I've provided in my original question my implementation of my kill_proc() function.

Comment: See the update, which is an entirely different approach.

Comment: Thanks Booboo! This one seems to work!

Comment: Then perhaps you can *accept* the answer (and maybe even upvote it).

Comment: Sure, I will.
Pretty advanced stuff!
I expected that getting the stdout & stderr would be easier...:)
Can you explain the code a bit?

Comment: BTW, changing the example to use ping, shows the stdout better,
so:
cmd_full = ['ping', '-t', 'localhost']

Comment: Thanks Booboo! BTW, your previous solution works as well if I kill the process properly (with my kill_proc() function) and only then run the proc.communicate() command. Because it is killed, it will not hang there forever, but the stdout & stderr are there to read. 
Your comment about flushing the stdout is super important, that's the reason I didn't see before that the previous solution didn't work with my change.
If you add that answer as an additional answer, I will accept it as well.

Comment: As long as you have your two solutions and your comment explains the other one, readers will see both. But if you care to post an answer to your own question, I will upvote it. Btw, you can upvote multiple answers but you can only accept one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to the problem.
This example uses `ping -t localhost` to simulate an infinite process (infinite ping sequence). Once timeout reaches, the function `kill_proc()` will kill the 'ping.exe' process and `stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()` will get its stdout and stderr.

**Note 1:** For some reason `proc.kill()` nor `proc.terminate()` really kill the process, so I had to kill it differently with the `kill_proc()` function directly with the process name. Calling `proc.communicate()` without killing it first, will return to the infinite process waiting for it to finish (which may never happen).

**Note 2:** As written by Booboo, the executable being run by subprocess.Popen must flush its output as it proceeds, otherwise we will not be able to read it.

```
import sys
import time
import psutil


def kill_proc():
    process_name = "ping.exe"  # process name
    for process in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
        try:
            if process.info['name'].lower() == process_name.lower():
                print(f"{process_name} is already running. Terminating it...")
                process.terminate()
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass


def main():
    import subprocess
    import os

    cmd_full = ['ping', '-t', 'localhost']
    cwd = '.'  # Current directory
    TIMEOUT_SEC = 3
    env = os.environ

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_full, cwd=cwd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, env=env)

    try:
        stdout, stderr = proc.wait(timeout=TIMEOUT_SEC)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
        print('Timeout occurred.')
        kill_proc()
        #proc.kill() # this one doesn't really kill the process, so I wrote the one above
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()  # Reissue call to get stdout & stderr
    ... # etc.

    print('stdout output:')
    print(stdout, end='')

    print()
    print('stderr output:')
    print(stderr, end='')

    return_code = proc.returncode
    print()
    print('return code =', return_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```